# When is a constant pointer (not a pointer to a constant) in a function prototype required for the code to be correct?

Tags: c, constants

While reviewing code, I occasionally see function prototypes with constant pointers like:

```
void Foo(int * const bar);
```

Often a programmer using such a function does not understand what he actually sees and the function is later used like this:

```
const int bla = 0;
Foo((int* const) &bla);
```

which, as far as I understand, results in undefined behavior. In this case, the constant pointer caused confusion.

My question is: When is a constant pointer (not a pointer to a constant) in a function prototype required for the code to be correct?

Comment: It lets you identify errors at compile time by making modifying `const` pointers as an error

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword is just used to avoid mistakes generating compilation errors if the variable is touched and to optimize code making the assumption that the variable does not change. **It is never *required***. It also is of no interest at all to the caller, since C passes all parameters by value.

Both the usages of `const`, either `const int *` or `int * const`, are just a contract between the programmer and the compiler. They are never required.

Comment: Does it mean that the pointer will not be touched, or the value pointing to will not be touched?

Comment: `int *const x;` means that the pointer itself (i.e. the variable `x` itself) will not be modified, while `const int *x;` means that the data pointed to by `x` will not be modified.

Comment: Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it is not what OP asked. They specifically said "not a pointer to a constant" in the title.